# Yii2 ActiveRecord not saving?

Tags: php, yii2

**view:**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password2')->passwordInput(['value'=>''])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Password2')) ?>
```

**model**

```
Class Admin extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    public $password2;

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'app_users';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fullname', 'username', 'password', 'password2', 'role_id'], 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique'],
            ['password2', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>Yii::t('app', 'Passwords don\'t match') ],
            [['role_id', 'alive'], 'integer'],
            ['image', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2],
            [['access_deadline'], 'safe']
        ];
    }
```

I am trying to save the model but AN ERROR throws: `"Password2 is required!"`. How to bypass this error and successfully save the model?

Comment: Remove password2 from first rule with validator 'required'

Comment: No. I need my "re-type password" field to be required, but I do not need to store this field in the DB

Comment: I think that password2 field will not be stored in database. Are you sure that the errors you get is from database insert query and not from Yii validation rules?

Comment: Yes, I have validation error that "password2 is required"

Comment: Are you trying to save your model in create or update method?

Comment: Can you include the controller code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can How  bypass this error successfully save the model using

```
$model->save(false);
```

In this way the value are saved inb db without perform validation

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you have the field `Password2` in your SQL DB and it is a required column, which means you will not be able to save any model in the DB with this field being `null`, even though you don't actually need it, in the database.

The way I see it, you have three options.

- you can go to your controller and, right before `$model->save()`, you can give the `$model->password2` field a value of your choice.
- you can also go to your database and make this fild not required. Take out the `NOT NULL` option from this field in SQL. However KEEP THE REQUIRED option in your model. This way you will not need it in your database, but you will need it in your form, to check the user typed his password right.
- use the suggestion scaisEdge gave you

Hope it helps. Good luck!